# Hide sidebar component some page in VUE.js

Tags: vue.js

I am working with Vue.js and I have a question.

Is there a way to hide `sidebar` component only some page ?
This is my code below.

router.js

```
  const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    redirect: '/home',
    component: () => import('@/layout/MainLayout'),
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        name: 'Home',
        component: () => import('Views/Home.vue'),
      }, 
    ],
  },
  {
    path: '/subpage',
    redirect: '/subpage/subpage',
    component: () => import('@/layout/MainLayout'),
    children: [ 
      {
        path: 'subpage',
        name: 'Subpage',
        component: () => import('Views/Subpage/Subpage.vue'),
      }, 
    ],
  }, 
];
```

MainLayout.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="content" class="content"> 
    <router-view></router-view> 
    <Sidebar></Sidebar> 
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Sidebar from '@/components/Sidebar.vue'; 

export default {
  components: {
    Sidebar, 
  },
};
</script>
```

Do I need to make another layout? like `MainLayout2.vue`

Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add meta information to vue routes. Add the sidebar key to the routes you want to hide

```
{
path: '/subpage',
redirect: '/subpage/subpage',
component: () => import('@/layout/MainLayout'),
children: [ 
  {
    path: 'subpage',
    name: 'Subpage',
    meta:{sidebar:false}
    component: () => import('Views/Subpage/Subpage.vue'),
  }, 
],
},
```

Then in your layout component, make a computed property to check if the current route needs to hide the sidebar

```
computed:{
    shouldShowSidebar(){
        return this.$route.meta.sidebar!==false;
    }
}
```

Then use this computed property to conditionally hide the sidebar on specific routes

```
<Sidebar v-if="shouldShowSidebar"></Sidebar>
```

You can add `meta:{sidebar:false}` to any route you want the sidebar to be hidden on